# Error:null value in entry: processorListFile=null

Tags: android, gradle

Ошибка при билде проекта. В чем может быть проблема?

```
Error:null value in entry: processorListFile=null
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил путем удаление папки `.gradle` в папке проекта.
Чтобы найти эту папку измените тип отображения файлов с `Android` на `Project`